# The best way to store a lot of static local mp4 video files in Xcode project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa-touch

There is a requirement where I need to place many mp4 video files in an Xcode project. The purpose is to make the app capable of working in offline mode.

The number of video files will always be static and so will the rest of the information for the app. This will make the app fully capable to work in offline mode.

Which is the fastest and most reliable option to do this?

1. Core data
2. NSArchiver
3. NSUserDefaults
4. Property List / Plist

The project is in Swift 4.

Comment: None of your options make any sense. Store the files as files in your app bundle.

Comment: Are you downloading files when app has internet connection? as per your description you have static data, which you can directly add into your source folder and you can show list of videos by reading via app bundle. The above mentioned ways are suitable when you are getting data run time.

Comment: No i am not downloading any data. Should i download it from cloud ? or just place the videos in project bundle.....

Comment: Make sure, Videos size does not exceed a limit of App store app size.

Comment: what is the max app size for ios ?